# Conditional validation in zod

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, zod

I'm working with a validation schema using Zod, where I have an items field that represents an array of objects. In this scenario, I'm specifically using it for invoice items. Each item is an object with various properties.

I'm facing a challenge in defining a validation schema that enforces the following condition: If the `id` property within an item is set, then all other fields within that item should be optional (indicating that the item is being updated). Conversely, if the `id` property is not set, then all other fields should be required (indicating that a new item is being created).

How can I achieve this conditional validation in Zod?

```
items: z.array(z.object({
        id: z.number({required_error: "'id' is required", invalid_type_error: "'id' must be a number"}).positive("'id' must be a positive number").optional(),
        articleId: z.number({required_error: "'articleId' is required", invalid_type_error: "'articleId' must be a number"}).positive("'articleId' must be a positive number"),
        sku: z.number({required_error: "'sku' is required", invalid_type_error: "'sku' must be a number"}).positive("'sku' must be a positiv number"),
        description: z.string({ required_error: "'description' is required" }).nonempty("'description' cannot be empty").max(1000, { message: "'description' is too long" }),
        quantity: z.number({required_error: "'quantity' is required", invalid_type_error: "'quantity' must be a number"}).positive("'quantity' must be a positive number"),
        price: z.number({required_error: "'price' is required", invalid_type_error: "'price' must be a number"}).positive("'price' must be a positive number"),
        term: z.enum(["month", "year", "flat", "piece"], { required_error: "'term' is required" }),
    })),
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [`z.or()`](https://zod.dev/?id=or)?

```js
const schema = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
}).or(z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  whatever: z.number(),
  etc: z.string()
}))


type T = z.infer<typeof schema>
/*
 T: {id: string} | {name: string; whatever: number; etc: string}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using superRefine method to add conditional validation to your previous schema like this:

```js
const itemSchema = z
  .object({
    id: z
      .number({
        required_error: "'id' is required",
        invalid_type_error: "'id' must be a number",
      })
      .positive("'id' must be a positive number")
      .optional(),
    articleId: z
      .number({
        required_error: "'articleId' is required",
        invalid_type_error: "'articleId' must be a number",
      })
      .positive("'articleId' must be a positive number"),
    sku: z
      .number({
        required_error: "'sku' is required",
        invalid_type_error: "'sku' must be a number",
      })
      .positive("'sku' must be a positive number"),
    description: z
      .string({ required_error: "'description' is required" })
      .nonempty("'description' cannot be empty")
      .max(1000, { message: "'description' is too long" }),
    quantity: z
      .number({
        required_error: "'quantity' is required",
        invalid_type_error: "'quantity' must be a number",
      })
      .positive("'quantity' must be a positive number"),
    price: z
      .number({
        required_error: "'price' is required",
        invalid_type_error: "'price' must be a number",
      })
      .positive("'price' must be a positive number"),
    term: z.enum(["month", "year", "flat", "piece"], {
      required_error: "'term' is required",
    }),
  })
  .superRefine(
    (
      { id, articleId, sku, description, quantity, price, term },
      refinementContext
    ) => {
      if (id !== undefined) {
        // If id is defined, make all other fields optional
        return;
      } else {
        // If id is not defined, make all other fields required
        const fieldsToCheck = [
          "articleId",
          "sku",
          "description",
          "quantity",
          "price",
          "term",
        ];
        for (const field of fieldsToCheck) {
          if (eval(field) === undefined) {
            refinementContext.addIssue({
              code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
              message: `${field} is required when 'id' is not set`,
              path: [field],
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  );

const items = z.array(itemSchema);

const validItem = {
  articleId: 123,
  sku: 456,
  description: "Product ABC",
  quantity: 5,
  price: 10.99,
  term: "month",
};

const isValid = items.safeParse([validItem]);

console.log(isValid.success); // Should output true

const invalidItem = {
  articleId: 123,
  sku: 456,
  //description is missing
  quantity: 5,
  price: 10.99,
  term: "month",
};

const isInvalid = items.safeParse([invalidItem]);

console.log(isInvalid.success); // Should output false
```

This code was adapted from this repository on GitHub, which contained an implementation similar to yours:  https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/discussions/938#discussioncomment-6952970

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Can you explain whats eval is doing here?